# fetch id from view and pass to another controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have **2 table** as follows

**project**

```
id | name | address
```

**boq**

```
id | project_id |item_no | description
```

**project_id** is the foreign key. then i have loaded the all data from project table.then i want to load all the data in to boq table which related to project id when click on the project name. here is my code.but it doesn't work.any one can plz help me.

**controller**

```
   function show_boq() {
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);
$data['projects'] = $this->project_list_model->show_projects();
$data['boq'] = $this->project_list_model->show_boq($project_id);
$this->load->view('boq_doc', $data);
}
```

**model**

```
 function show_boq($id){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('boq');
$this->db->where('project_id',$data);
$this->db->join('project', 'project.id = boq.project_id');
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
return $result;
}
```

**view**

```
<?php foreach ($boq as $boq): ?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $boq->id; ?></td>

<td><?php echo $boq->item_no; ?></td>

<td><?php echo $boq->description; ?> </td>

</tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: you means to said, you get no values through function : show_boq()

Comment: In the **view** , the `foreach` loop syntax is wrong as you are giving both name as same. change it like `foreach ($boq as $bq)` and access like `$bq->id`. If still not work please put your error..

Comment: function show_boq($data){ change this $data to $id. As in query you are looking for $id which is missing

Comment: Message: Missing argument 1 for Project_list::show_boq()

Filename: controllers/project_list.php

Line Number: 18


Message: Undefined variable: project_id

Filename: controllers/project_list.php


Unknown column 'boq.project.id' in 'on clause'

SELECT * FROM (`boq`) JOIN `project` ON `project`.`id` = `boq`.`project`.`id` WHERE `project_id` IS NULL

Comment: Replace `$this->db->join('project', 'project.id = boq.project.id');` to `$this->db->join('project', 'project.id = boq.project_id');` and `$this->db->where('project_id',$id);`  to `$this->db->where('project_id',$data);` for controller error you are not passing the `$project_id`

Comment: raj i have edited the code as u said.but still error is coming.

Message: Undefined variable: project_id

Filename: controllers/project_list.php

Message: Undefined variable: data

Filename: models/project_list_model.php

Comment: Do one thing echo project_id inside function body and check variable have value

Comment: use echo $this->db->last_query(); this will print your query and you get to know, how your query interpret with database..

Comment: In your model in your db where you have $data but should be $id instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Model like this. Use project table as first and boq table as second.

```
function show_boq($data){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('project');
    $this->db->join('boq', 'project.id = boq.project_id');
    $this->db->where('project.id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();
}
```

And view file is

```
<?php 

        if (is_array($boq) || is_object($boq))
        {

        foreach ($boq as $row): ?>

            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row->id; ?></td>

            <td><?php echo $row->item_no; ?></td>

            <td><?php echo $row->description; ?> </td>

            </tr>
              <?php endforeach; 
        }
?>
```

Comment: Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/boq_doc.php

Message: Undefined variable: project_id

Filename: controllers/project_list.php

Message: Undefined variable: id

Filename: models/project_list_model.php

Comment: I think in table there is no values for the given id

Comment: If there is no values use if condition before foreach like i updated in code.

Comment: In controller you are assign `$id = $this->uri->segment(3);`. But while passing to model  you used `$project_id` in `->show_boq($project_id)`. Is it correct?

Comment: i have changed the code as u said.$data['boq'] = $this->project_list_model->show_boq($id); but come same error

Comment: Manually give the valid id and check once like `$data['boq'] = $this->project_list_model->show_boq(1);`

Comment: mani now it shows only one error  Undefined variable: id

Filename: models/project_list_model.php

Comment: change in model `$data` as `$id` like `function show_boq($id){`

Comment: mani now there is no error.but there is no value also.plz help me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116035/discussion-between-mani-and-ashik).